# force security permission through the directory tree?

Tags: windows, security, directory

Currently, there is large directory tree with differnt security permissions.  We need to add another Security permission for all of the folders, and files without changing all the inherited permissions.  How can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [cacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx)

```
cacls /e /t /g "my group":f
```

this example command edits the ACL for the current directory and all subdirectories and grants the *my group* group full control by adding it to the current ACL

Answer (score 0):

If the child folders have inheritance enabled (which they do by default) then simply add the security principal to the parent folder, set the permissions, and they will be inherited by the child folders.